# How do I solve a "An error occured while mounting /sys/bus/usb/drivers." error?

Tags: 12.04, mount

I have got this message during the startup ubuntu 12.04:

```
An error occured while mounting /sys/bus/usb/drivers.  
Press S to skip mounting... and so on...
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved [here](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2010/05/03/howto-fix-an-error-occurred-while-mounting-ubuntu-lucid-10-04/)

1. `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
2. Find the following line
3. `none /sys/bus/usb/drivers usbfs devgid=126,devmode=664 0 0`
4. Add a # in front of them to comment it out
5. Save & Exit.